# ngClass isn't seeing a variable updated via a service subscription

Tags: angular

I'm trying to circumvent the `routerLinkActiveOptions` `exact:true` to allow me to place an active class on a link that is root plus an id: `site.com/:id`

Obviously, that won't work with RouterLinkActive since the `/` will match every route. So I have a service I subscribe to to report the current url and params, and it works great for string interpolation, but when I try to interpret the variable in a directive, it gets ignored. Just wondering why the template gets updated when the variable changes, but the logic that relies on the variables won't get re-evaluated.

```
%div {{url}}
.tab-group.tab-group-rosters
  %a.tab.tab-roster(routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" routerLink="/" [ngClass]="url === 'roster' ? 'active' : ''")
```

^ This code works on a page load, but not on subsequent navigation. However, the contents of the div update as expected.

I tried making the url an Observable and piping it through `| async` but it complained.

I also tried `this.ref.detectChanges();` in the function that processes the subscription, but that didn't work.

Can someone clue me in on the accepted way to re-run template logic when a url changes?

Answer (score 0):

umm, so, it turns out that routerLinkActive="active" on the same link was messing with things. Maybe it was removing the "active" after the ngClass was setting it. Looks like I have to set the class in full manual mode if I decide to monkey with it.